# sending mail rejected due to TLS verification

Tags: go, smtp, starttls

For testing my app, I need to send a mail over my companies mailhost.

Unfortunately I have to use a tunnel to connect to that host and so sending mail is rejected because:

```
tls: failed to verify certificate: x509: certificate is valid for *.example.com, example.com, not host.docker.internal
```

Is there any way around this? Can I disable TLS?

I'm using github.com/jhillyerd/enmime

**Update after 2 comments**

1. I do **not** want to switch of TLS on the mailhost. I simply want to tell my net/smtp's Sendmail or enmime's Send to not do TLS verification. I already achieved that by copying Sendmail's code, leaving out the TLS-Part. But I don't like that approach as it feels very "hacky".
2. I'm working in a VPN and there are no credentials required when sending mails, as the mailhost can only be reached by a small set of known hosts.
3. This is also why I need a tunnel through a jumphost in order to reach the mailhost from my developer machine:

Dockercontainer --> DevMac ---> Jumphost ---> Mailhost

So I do a

`ssh -L9925:mailhost.example.com:25 me@jumphost.example.com`

That's why I have defined the mailhost to be "host.docker.internal:9925".

Maybe there is another idea how I can reach the mailhost by its real name?

**Update after finding a workaround**

I now simply add on my developer container an entry to `/etc/hosts` pointing my real `mailhost.example.com` to the IP of `host.docker.internal` .

That way TLS verification succeeds.

Comment: Not clear from your question, but you can also specify a `Host:  something.example.com` which should pass TLS verification.

Comment: A tunnel in and of itself should not prevent your IT guys from setting up a proper TLS certificate for their mailhost and have a proper DNS setup. Actually, would you send your private credentials to a host you aren't absolutely positively sure is the one you want to authenticate against? The setup as it is allows for MITM attacks any interested middle schooler would be able to pull off.